# Javascript OOP return value from function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have javascript object defined like this:

```
function SocialMiner() 
{


var verbose=true;

var profileArray=new Array();

var tabUrl;

this.getTabUrl=function()
{
    logToConsole("getTabUrl is called");


    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
    {
        tabUrl = tab.url;
        logToConsole(tabUrl);

    });

    return tabUrl;
}   `
```

Then I call this function on SocialMiner ojbect like this:

```
 var pageUrl=miner.getTabUrl();
 miner.logToConsole(pageUrl);
```

What is the reason that first call to `logToConsole` successfully prints the Url, while second one says undefined. Am I not returning the same value from the function ?

Update: This is how I have defined logToConsole:

```
function logToConsole(text) 
    {
        if (verbose)
            console.log(text);
    }

    this.logToConsole=logToConsole;
```

Comment: Im missing something here; you don't seem to have defined a `logToConsole` method on your SocialMiner object. You've made a `getTabUrl` method, but no `logToConsole`.

Comment: @Tejs: Please check out the update I have made.

Comment: Your other question got closed as a duplicate, so I'm not sure if you saw the edit to my answer ([bottom half of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221413/javascript-oop-confusion/6221599#6221599)), but I think the issue is actually timing of setting/getting because of the asynch nature of your calls...

Comment: You are right, the issue was solved. Sorry for marking it late as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, you are calling logToConsole as if it is a function of the miner object, which is is not.

```
miner.logToConsole
```

**Edit**

Per comments about github example, this should make the logToConsole function par of the SocialMiner object.  However, I didn't read the class thoroughly, so proceed with caution with regards to how it is intended to be used.

```
this.logToConsole=function(text) 
{
    if (verbose)
        console.log(text);
}
```

Comment: @Madhur, your update still doesn't have logToConsole as a method of SocialMiner. You're calling it as if it's a method of SocialMiner, but it's not.

Comment: logToConsole is not being attached to your SocialMiner still. You would need to do `SocialMiner.prototype.logToConsole = function() { }` to attach it to your objects.

Comment: @Madhur: It still looks like the function is defined outside of the miner class.

Comment: @Madhur, the SocialMiner function does not define logToConsole as part of the class. It appears to be an inline function to be called when SocialMiner is constructed. If you want to be able to use it as part of the Miner object, then you should probably construct it as such. I will edit my post as an example.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that logToConsole is defined somewhere globally; in any case, it is not a member of our SocialMiner class.  Try this:

```
var pageUrl=miner.getTabUrl();
logToConsole(pageUrl);
```