# javascript OOP Confusion

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript OOP return value from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220133/javascript-oop-return-value-from-function)

I have a class defined like this

```
function SocialMiner(tabUrl) 
{
    var verbose=true;

    var profileArray=new Array();

    this.tabUrl=tabUrl;

    this.getTabUrl=function(callback)
    {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
        {


            callback(tab.url);
        });
    }   

    this.setTabUrlValue=function(pageUrl)
    {
        this.tabUrl=pageUrl;
        console.log("22"+this.tabUrl);   //this statement shows url correctly
    }
}
```

When I call this method like these

```
 miner.getTabUrl(miner.setTabUrlValue);

   miner.logToConsole("1"+miner.tabUrl);   //This statement returns undefined
```

The `console.log` inside callback correctly outputs `url` , however, the `tabUrl` property of `miner` ojbect is undefined , as seen in second `console.log`. Why is it so ?

Comment: does the `logToConsole` method exists ?

Comment: so there have been 3 proper answers to this question, the problem is a misunderstanding of what "this" is. Why you haven't been able to get a working answer is your code snippet is highly dependant on the rest of your script. I would highly recommend going to jsfiddle.net, and getting a more generic answer together to illustrate your problem. This will make it easier to both understand your question, and give you a proper answer.

Comment: @Matt : see the corrected code, Its still not working. miner.TabUrl comes undefined in second line. https://gist.github.com/1005576

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the post in your reply contains a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a tricky beast in JavaScript and as others have pointed out is the key to the issue. The problem with using `this` everywhere is that it's value can change depending on who/where the function is called from (for example, see the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods in JavaScript). I'm guessing that if you wrote the value of `this` to the console in the the callback from the `chrome.tabs.getSelected` function you'd find it isn't your miner any more.

The solution is to capture a reference to the `this` that you're actually interested in when you know for sure it's the right one & then use that reference from then on. Might make more sense to see it commented in-line in your example:

```
function SocialMiner(tabUrl) 
{
    //At this point we know "this" is our miner object, so let's store a
    //reference to it in some other (not so transient) variable...
    var that = this;

    var verbose=true;

    var profileArray=new Array();

    this.tabUrl=tabUrl;

    this.getTabUrl=function(callback)
    {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab)
        {
            //at this point "this" is whatever the "chrome.tabs.getSelected"
            //method has decided it is (probably a reference to the tab or something)
            callback(tab.url);
        });
    }   

    this.setTabUrlValue=function(pageUrl)
    {
        //because this can be called from anywhere, including the chrome callback
        //above, who knows what "this" refers to here (but "that" is definitely
        //still your miner)
        that.tabUrl=pageUrl;
        console.log("22"+that.tabUrl);
    }
}
```

You can see how much `this` shifts around in libraries that use callbacks heavily like jQuery, where often `this` is set to convenient values, but certainly not the same `this` that was logically in scope when you made the initial call.

**EDIT**: Looking at the [full source (& example) you posted](https://gist.github.com/1005576), this is just a timing issue where obviously the `chrome.tabs.getSelected` is returning asynchronously after your "second" call to log goes through...

```
console.log("5");
miner.getTabUrl(miner.setTabUrlValue);   //setTabUrlValue is logging with '22'
console.log("6");
miner.logToConsole("1"+miner.tabUrl);
console.log("7");


// Output:
5
6
1 undefined       //the chrome.tabs.getSelected hasn't returned yet...
7
22 http://url     //now it has (so if you tried to use miner.tabUrl now you'd be all good...
```

The solution is to put all the stuff after the get/set into the callback, since you don't want anything happening until after that tabUrl is finished being set... so something like this:

```
console.log("5");
miner.getTabUrl(function(pageUrl) {
    miner.setTabUrlValue(pageUrl);
    console.log("6");
    miner.logToConsole("1"+miner.tabUrl);
    console.log("7");
});
```

Hopefully that will see you getting your results in the order you expect them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I am using this implementation now as seen in gist. https://gist.github.com/1005576 However, second line is still printing undefined, for miner.tabUrl

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to save a reference to `this` within the constructor (available later on via closure):

```
var that = this; //in the top of the SocialMiner constructor function
```

and in `setTabUrlValue` use:

```
that.tabUrl=pageUrl;
```

I suspect running a method as a function (`callback`) loses scope, i.e. doesn't know of any `this` anymore. In other words, it runs within the scope of the constructor, not as a method of the instance using it. A variable referencing `this` in the constructor scope *is* available to the function, and `that` points to the right `this` on instance creation.

You could also force `callback` to run in the current instance scope like this:

```
callback.call(this,tab.url);
```

In that case you can leave `this.tabUrl=pageUrl;` as it is.

This is an simplification of your code. The methods return `this` to be able to directly reference a property of the instance (see `console.log` last line):

```
function Some(){
     var that = this; // note: not used in this example
     this.getA = function(callback){
         someval = 'foobar';
         callback.call(this,someval);
         return this;
     };
     this.getB = function(val){
         this.val = val;
         return this;
     };
}
var some = new Some;
console.log( some.getA(some.getB).val ); //=> foobar
```

Taking a look @ your code again, I think you're loosing scope twice, because `callback` is called from within another callback. That's why I think your code on that spot should be:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(
      null, 
      function(tab) {
        callback.call(that,tab.url); //< use that here
      }
);
```

Furthermore, in you code @ github, I don't see any instantiation of the `miner` instance.

Comment: Can you explain more, I tried this but didn't work. See the gist here:https://gist.github.com/1005576

Comment: Hi Madhur Ahuja, see the edited answer. Maybe I'll look later, but for now it's late here and time to get some sleep ;~)

Comment: Have a good night, but still no luck :(

Comment: Thanks. I don't see `.logToConsole` defined in your constructor, may that be the problem?

Comment: @Kooilnc: Check out the full code here https://gist.github.com/1005576

Answer (score 1):

I think this happens because closure vars do not survive a function call.

Comment: Can you elaborate, I think its because call back is executed asynch. Isn't it ?

Comment: The call to callback() doesn't preserve the object that's being operated on. That is a static function call. What you would have to do is apply the callback to the object as a method: callback.call(this, pageUrl);

Comment: @Zath: The above solution doesn't seem to work